# Remove rows with 3 or more NA values - R

Tags: r

I would like to remove all rows with 3 or more NA values - below is an example of my data set (but the actual data set has 95,000 rows)

```
Plot_ID  Tree_ID   Dbh13   Dbh08  Dbh03  Dbh93_94
106       6         236     132    123     132    
204       5         NA      NA     NA      142
495       8         134     NA     NA      102
984       12        NA      123    110     97
```

So that it looks like this

```
Plot_ID  Tree_ID   Dbh13   Dbh08  Dbh03  Dbh93_94
  106       6         236     132    123     132    
  495       8         134     NA     NA      102
  984       12        NA      123    110     97
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Plot_ID  Tree_ID   Dbh13   Dbh08  Dbh03  Dbh93_94
106       6         236     132    123     132    
204       5         NA      NA     NA      142
495       8         134     NA     NA      102
984       12        NA      123    110     97

df1    <- read.table(con<-file("clipboard"),header=T)

cnt_na <- apply(df1, 1, function(z) sum(is.na(z)))

df1[cnt_na < 3,]
```

> ```
>   Plot_ID Tree_ID Dbh13 Dbh08 Dbh03 Dbh93_94
> 1     106       6   236   132   123      132
> 3     495       8   134    NA    NA      102
> 4     984      12    NA   123   110       97
> ```